# Force App opening on another Android Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, device, communication

i've got a simple question (but i expect hard answers :D )
Is there a way to realize the following scenario?

App X on Device A (with Android) forces App Y on Device B (with Android) to open itself.
The communication could happen in wifi or bluetooth or other kind of protocol.

Obviously, after a enrollment/binding phase between the two devices.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is, one simple way would be to run a background service on the second device and use GCM (or any other service/protocol you like) to send a message to the second device, the service then processes the message and fires and intent which opens the app on the device.

Another way would be using Bluetooth if you need local communication instead of using the internet. (Also NFC and others should work).